# how write a type definition for a HoC using flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, higher-order-components

I'm trying to write a flow type for a HoC that will return a component and add a prop isVisible to it

```
type VisibleProps = {isVisible: boolean}

const VisibleComp = <P, S>(Component: Class<React.Component<void, P, S>>)
  : Class<React.Component<void, P&VisibleProps, S> => 
  class WrappedComponent extends React.Component<void, P&VisibleProps, S> {
      render() {
          return <Component {...this.props} isVisible={true} />
      }
  }
```

I try several things without success :(

Answer (score 0):

Digging in the flow issues, I found this issue which solve my problem 
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3241

hope it helps.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';

type Visible = {isVisible: boolean}
type WrappedProps<P,Visible> = P & Visible  

const injectVisible = <P: Object>(
  Component: Class<React.Component<*, WrappedProps<P, Visible>, *>>
) => class VisibleHoC extends React.Component<*, P, Visible> {
      state: Visible
      render() {
          return <Component {...this.props} isVisible={true} />
      }
  }

class Component extends React.Component {
  props: Visible
  render() {
    return <div> {this.props.isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}</div>
  }
}

const VisibleComponent = injectVisible(Component)
```

Comment: It seems to me that you don't actually have type checking on whether `injectVisible` correctly adds the required `isVisible` prop to the wrapped `Component`. If you remove `isVisible={true}`, it won't throw any flow errors, even though `VisibleComponent` would not have received an `isVisible` prop after all. I'm trying to understand how to correctly flow type HOC's myself, so I'd be curious to understand more about your approach and whether I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: FYI, I have my own somewhat related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267391/flow-error-when-passing-props-through-flow-typed-higher-ordered-components

Comment: you're right It only type check for component passed to the HoC. My first solution implies to type the Hoc component using a $Diff<P, Visible> but not workd (probably related to a $Diff bug)