# Flow error when passing props through flow-typed higher ordered components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, flowtype, higher-order-components

Consider the following code. `Wrapper1` renders `Wrapper2`, passing into it the `Final` component as a prop, along with a couple props that `Final` ultimately expects, `finalProp` and `w2prop`. `Wrapper2` then renders the component passed into it, passing along all its props to that rendered component. In this case, the `Final` component is getting rendered by `Wrapper2`, and it is receiving its needed props.

However, Flow does not understand this. I'm receiving the following two errors:

> 1. property `finalProp` Property not found in object type See also: React element `Wrapper2`
> 2. property `w2prop` Property not found in object type See also: React element `Wrapper2`

```
type FinalT = {
  finalProp: number,
  w2prop: number,
};

function Final(props: FinalT): React.Element<*> {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.finalProp}
      {props.w2prop}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Wrapper1(): React.Element<*> {
  return (
    <Wrapper2
      component={Final}
      finalProp={7}
      w2prop={7}
    />
  );
}

type Wrapper2T = {
  component: (*) => React.Element<*>,
};

function Wrapper2(props: Wrapper2T): React.Element<*> {
  const Cmp = props.component;

  return <Cmp {...props} />;
}
```

Based on the error message, Flow obviously understands that `Final` is getting rendered by `Wrapper2`. However, it fails to realize that the necessary props are being provided. I find this strange. If it can tell that `props.component` in `Wrapper2` is `Final`, then I'd expect it to know the full scope of what's in `props`.

If I add `finalProp` and `w2prop` to the `type Wrapper2T`, then Flow is happy. But that's a non-starter, since `Wrapper2` is supposed to be a higher order component that is agnostic about what component it ultimately renders.

Is there a different way I'm supposed to annotate these flow types? Or a different pattern for creating & rendering these components? I think what I have above is a standard pattern in React, so there must be some solution.

Comment: Given your types, Flow wouldn't actually know finalProp and w2prop were passed into Wrapper2T.component. At the very least, you probably will have to fix the problem that are spreading props in Wrapper2, but the props of Wrapper2 is Wrapper2T which does not have finalProp or w2prop information.

Comment: It looks like there might be a solution here via generic parameters